# Push Notification push appears twice?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My app's Push Notification push appears twice. But I have added a code to push only one time as follows :-

My app code

```
receive message:{
    aps =     {
        alert = "\U5b89\U7881\U63a8\U64ad\U6e2c\U8a66\U4e2d~~~";
        badge = 1;
        sound = default;
    };
}
receive message:{
    aps =     {
        alert = "";
        badge = 0;
        sound = "";
    };
}
```

What should I do ? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you're only sending the notification once? My guess is that you have the device registered multiple times or the send code is getting run twice. It would be very abnormal for Apple's servers to screw up and send the message twice.

Comment: i use MAC mini open google chrome web push notification is there such a situation,but i use windows pc open google chrome web push notification is normal!!I can not understand＠＠"

Comment: you should probably post the code you are using to send the push notification if you want a more detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get duplicate push messages on your device when there are multiple registrations of the same device. If this is the case, check the code where the device registration happens.

Otherwise, i hope this would help:-
[Duplicate push notifications on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074529/duplicate-push-notifications-on-ios)